this challenge concerning state or props or whatever it's called in React
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
    const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([])
    function messCount(){
        setMessages(prevMessage => prevMessage.length)
    }
    /**
     * Challenge:
     * - Only display the <h1> below if there are unread messages
     */
    return (
        <div>
            {messages.length && <h1>You have {messages.length} unread messages!</h1>}
        </div>
    )
}


this is the code and the challenge commented out, i have no idea what to do please help
i tried setting up a second state with integer 0 as default, then i tried to insert with curlybrackets into the jsx markup but it didnt truly work

How would one determine if messages are "unread" or not?  What specifically have you tried and what specifically didn't work as expected?

I don't know those things that's why i am asking. i tried using the .length thingy but it didnt quite work  because if i clear the array so that it's just an empty array then i get a zero on screen when it's supposed to not display anything"

it should display how many items (messsages) are in the array and only display the h1 at all if there are messages in the array, if that makes sense?

@JohannesPettersson: "it should display how many items (messsages) are in the array and only display the h1 at all if there are messages in the array" - In that case, what have you tried in order to accomplish this?  "i tried using the .length thingy" - Perhaps you could be more specific about the attempt and in what way it didn't work as expected?

okay i will try to explain better but keep in mind i'm quite dumb so dont expect muchconst [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([])
function messCount(){
setMessages(prevMessage => prevMessage.length)
}
/**
* Challenge:
* - Only display the  below if there are unread messages
*/
return (

{messages.length && You have {messages.length} unread messages!}
 this is what i tried i skipped a few thjings because there's a character cap

oh and what went wrong is that there's a zero (on the screen)if i delete all the items in the array, on the screen that is? and im only supposed to render the entire h1 thing if there is stuff in the array, not if the array is empty

import React from "react"
export default function App() {
const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([])
function messCount(){
setMessages(prevMessage => prevMessage.length)
}
/**
* Challenge:
* - Only display the  below if there are unread messages
*/
return (

{messages.length && You have {messages.length} unread messages!}

)
}
this is the entire code i tried

"i skipped a few thjings because there's a character cap" - That's because information about the problem, including relevant code, belongs in the question.  Not buried in comments.  We can appreciate that you're struggling, but help us to help you.

That's because information about the problem, including relevant code, belongs in the question. Not buried in comments yes okay i get you but again, im an idiot i am legit borderline retarded i am really doing my best here, sorry. also i did give you the entire code of what i tried

i managed to edit the OP with the code that i tried, that didnt quite work, because there is a zero rendered on the webpage when it isn't supposed to render anything when the array is empty, so if you try out the code and just set the default state to empty array you can seee that there's a zero being rendered? well it shouldnt and thats what i need help with, i think? @David

You're getting very close, the reason it shows 0 when the array is empty is because messages.length is a number, what you really want the left side of <div>{condition && element}</div> would be a boolean value.

@HaoWu how am i supposed to make a boolean value do this?

Yes, by replacing messages.length && ... with messages.length > 0 && ..., the left side becomes a boolean value. In React.js, boolean values are not renderable but numbers are. So when the left condition is false, there will be nothing rendered. But if you are not familiar with React's quirks like this, I suggest you to use David's approach instead of the && pattern to render elements conditionally.

You can solve the Challenge by dynamically rendering the <h1> element only when there are messages.
Here is the modified code:
import React from "react";

export default function App() {

    const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState(["a", "b"]);

    /**
     * Challenge:
     * - Only display the <h1> below if there are unread messages
     */

    return (
        <div>
            {/* Conditionally render the <h1> element */}

            {messages.length > 0 && (
                <h1>You have {messages.length} unread messages!</h1>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

Explanation:

We use a conditional rendering to render the <h1> element only if there are messages(messages.length > 0).
If there are unread messages, we display the count of message inside the <h1> element in place of _.


I guess this makes sense, maybe, but how am i supposed to come up with solutions like this?

Based on comments on the question above, it sounds like the specific problem you're asking about is:

there's a zero (on the screen)if i delete all the items in the array

That appears to be coming from this:
{messages.length && <h1>You have {messages.length} unread messages!</h1>}

The code is successfully interpreting messages.length as being falsy and not outputting the <h1> element.  However, the value of messages.length itself is still the result of this expression, and React is displaying that result.
You can expand this into a ternary conditional operation to control the result of the expression when the value is falsy.  For example:
{messages.length ? <h1>You have {messages.length} unread messages!</h1> : null}

In this case null will be the result of the expression when messages.length is 0, and React will output nothing for it.

Edit: Based on a comment below, if you must use the && operator then you can do this:
{messages.length > 0 && <h1>You have {messages.length} unread messages!</h1>}

This relies on the actual value false instead of the "falsy" value 0, and the former shouldn't output to the page.

Yes that does work but the challenge is supposed to be about using the && operator to achieve this same thing

@JohannesPettersson: I've updated the answer with another option.

there's also one problem more with using the ternary stuff and : null, when i add back stuff into the array it just returns undefined on scrimba

@JohannesPettersson: The code shown doesn't modify the array.  If you have some other code which results in some new problem then it may be worth posting a new question about that code.

yes i saw that @David but there's a new problem with using the : null it just says "undefined" when i save in scrimba even when i add stuff to the array

@JohannesPettersson: Since you've already indicated that you're not allowed to use the ternary conditional operator, it's not clear why other problems elsewhere in your code related to the ternary conditional operator are relevant.  Did you try the updated alternate suggestion above which uses the && operator instead?  If something related to the specific problem in the question above still isn't working, please clarify that and include the updated code.

Thanks but the problem now is that even though i add back items to the array it still doesnt render the h1?

@JohannesPettersson: Yes it does.

oh that did work, but why didnt it work when i did it? like, what was wrong?

@JohannesPettersson: I wouldn't know, I can't see your screen from here.  If you have specific code which isn't working as expected in a specific way then you are encouraged to provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what problem you are observing.

import React from "react"
export default function App() {
const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([])
function messCount(){
setMessages(prevMessage => prevMessage.length)
}
/**
* Challenge:
* - Only display the  below if there are unread messages
*/
return (

{messages.length && You have {messages.length} unread messages!}

)
} @David this was my code, from the OP

@JohannesPettersson: Ok.... And?  Is there a new question about this code?  Have you tried applying this answer to the original problem?  Is something not working as expected when you do that?  If so, what is the new updated code?  What is a [mcve] which demonstrates this new problem?  "this was my code" doesn't describe or demonstrate a specific problem, or ask any kind of question.

The problem is i could never think out the answer for myself. i need to be able to solve this kind of problems on my own, but i always have no idea where to even begin

bumping this because i still havent figured out how to do this?

@JohannesPettersson: Spamming comments on answers does not draw the attention you're hoping for.  What specific problem remains that relates to the original question above?  What changes have you made to the code and what specifically isn't working as expected?  Do you still even have a problem related to the original question, or do you have an entirely new problem for an entirely new question?  Take the time to clarify what you're asking.  "Bumping this" doesn't describe the problem.

Again, the problem is that i don't understand how i will ever be able to understand how to actually write code like this code snippet myself, and so my question is: How can i understand why these things work the way they work, when to use what concept, what these concepts even do, how to actually use my brain to apply whatever this is? In other words, how can i get to a point where i can actually write this level of code myself?

@JohannesPettersson: You'd improve your skills in programming the same way you improve your skills in anything anywhere in life... practice and experience.  Please stop pretending that your question has not been answered just because you didn't come up with the answer yourself.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

okay but i have been practicing for almost 1 year 6 months now and i am seriously not improving, so clearly i need something other than just practice, but idk what that is
